# Windows Hello login methods no longer working and Windows Hello set up interface wont start

Tags: login, windows-11-v22h2, windows-hello

I have a Dell XPS 15 9520 here running windows 11 pro (22H2). I had set up fingerprint login that worked previously, lately when I try to use it the login screen says that it is unavailable (I've only just now had time to try to fix it, so it's been this way for months)

I have disabled it and attempted to set it up again from scratch, the Windows Hello set up shows its welcome screen, I then click on 'Get Started', it asks for my PIN, I enter it, it then thinks for a few seconds and then the window closes and that's that.

The same thing happens when I try to set up facial recognition.

I'd like to use at least fingerprint as I found it useful. **What next?**

Comment: Download the Dell Fingerprint Driver and install / reinstall it. Then you should be able to set up Windows password.  You should restart before testing.

Comment: @John - The Dell fingerprint driver shouldn’t be necessary to work with Windows Hello.

Comment: There may be another driver for face identification. You would probably need that. It is a driver issue so far as I can see at this point.

Comment: One of the huge improvements to Windows 10, was Windows Hello, and in order sell certified OEM Windows hardware that supports biometrics (Windows Hello) requires integration with the built-in support that exists within Windows. I suspect if the author changed a security setting which affected Windows Hello, the simplest solution out of this state, is to disable Windows Hello then reenable it.